# How can I specify the following layout with RelativePanel?

Tags: xaml

```
+--+---+--+
|  |RED|  |
+------+  |
| BLUE |  |
+------+--+
```

I have tried a few different combinations of `RelativePanel.Align...` attached properties, but I can't quite seem to get things to work out the way I want.

```
<!-- this version overlays Red beneath Blue, but aligned on the right -->
<Rectangle x:Name="Red" RelativePanel.AlignRightWith="Blue" />
<Rectangle x:Name="Blue" />

<!-- this version shoves Blue half off-screen -->
<Rectangle x:Name="Red" />
<Rectangle x:Name="Blue" RelativePanel.AlignRightWith="Red" RelativePanel.Below="Red" />

<!-- this version is a circular dependency -->
<Rectangle x:Name="Red" RelativePanel.AlignRightWith="Blue" />
<Rectangle x:Name="Blue" RelativePanel.Below="Red" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were in your shoes, I would use a `Grid`.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Column="1" ... />
    <Rectangle Fill="Blue" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ... />
</Grid>
```

Comment: Yeah, it's easy-peasy to use a `Grid`, but I'm just trying out the new UAP controls and wanted to see what was possible with the `RelativePanel`. From what I'm learning, `RelativePanel` is a nice option, but at some points you will still have to fall back on explicit `Grid`-based layouts. FWIW, I'm pretty sure that the third option would *not* be a circular dependency error in the equivalent Android layout, so it would be nice if someone at MS noticed this question. :)